# Spring JMS CachingConnectionFactory with cachedProducers enabled

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am currently working on a project to set up  spring cachedConnectionFactory sessionCahceSize, please provide answers as to why a sessionCacheSize of 1 (for 3 destinations) registers 1+ (around 3) JMS cached message producers per destination?

The application is running in transacted mode with concurrent thread size as 1

Should I have to look into the strategy of identifying the idle cached producers and evicting the cached producers for optimization?

Comment: Turn on TRACE level logging for the connection factory to see all activity around producer caching.

Comment: Yes I turned on the trace, that's how I found that it is registering 2 times per destination when my concurrent thread is configured to be 1

Comment: Edit the question and add your trace log.

Comment: Here are the parameters

Comment: 1 - Concurrent Thread size, 1 - Session Cache Size and attached are the logs:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the thread names in your trace, which makes it harder to debug. However...

The producer/consumer cache is at the `Session` level. If you are sending messages on multiple threads you can end up with a cached producer for each cached session.

- Thread 1 checks out a session does a send (caching a new producer); checks the session back in.
- Thread 2 checks out the same session; does a send (using the cached producer).
- Thread 1 checks out a different session (because the first one is in use); does a send (caching a new producer for that dest/session).
- Thread 2 checks in the session

> sessionCacheSize of 3 (for 3 destinations)

It doesn't work that way; sessions are not tied to destinations; they are general sessions that will cache a producer for each destination it is used for.

Comment: Based on the above comments, should I have to look into the strategy of identifying the idle cached producers and evicting the cached producers for optimization?

Comment: I am not aware of a mechanism to do that (with the standard factory). Cached producers live as long as their owning Session.

Comment: does this mean that for a session that sends to three destinations (over a period of time) it will cache 3 producers? or it will only cache the most recent, and replace on new destinations?